# ServiceStack Identity Server plugin keeps redirecting infinitely after authorize endpoint

Tags: servicestack, identityserver4

I'm trying to integrate `ServiceStack.Authentication.IdentityServer` plugin with an Identity Server 4.

When calling the protected ServiceStack endpoint from browser, the browser redirects to the authorize endpoint as below

```
https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize?client_id=simplehr&scope=openid%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5004/auth/IdentityServer&response_type=code%20id_token&state=8749c226e65646079c53ba403b51ef3e&nonce=291873debfd14de8b360c11cffbba3db&response_mode=form_post
```

In this case, `https://localhost:5001` is my Identity Server 4, and `https://localhost:5004` is my ServiceStack server.

After this step, the browser sends a POST request to ServiceStack's IdentityServer auth provider endpoint as expected. However, this endpoint returns a 302 back to the Identity Server's authorize endpoint. The response looks like

```
Location: https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize?client_id=simplehr&scope=openid offline_access&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5004/auth/IdentityServer&response_type=code id_token&state=8749c226e65646079c53ba403b51ef3e&nonce=f13048835b6e47f09a8c86882d2db320&response_mode=form_post
```

Therefore, my browser falls into an infinite loop.

Could anybody shed some light on how I can get over this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried turning on some debug information in IdentityServer?  In The IdentityServer project within Startup.cs ConfigureServices method switch on some debugging;

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            }).AddDeveloperSigningCredential()   ...etc

Then run in Visual Studio and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue with the ServiceStack Community NuGet package, please raise an issue with the project directly:

https://github.com/wwwlicious/servicestack-authentication-identityserver

Please also note that ServiceStack's latest v5.5 Release includes [support for IdentityServer4 Auth in ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#using-identityserver4-auth-in-servicestack) via the [mvcidentityserver](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentityserver) .NET Core project template.